# Error in rendering qmd file to html file in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I was in a mood of experimenting how to render a python code (I don't use python) I got from the web to see how it is executed in Quarto. When I rendered it, a numberous requests poped up. I accepted many of them until I decided that there must be something wrong. After that, I couldn't render any R codes to the simple html file format. Also, when I open up a new file, I no longer have the sample codes to illustrate coding in qmd file that came along.

Here is my yml:

```
---
title: "Hello, Penguins"
subtitle: "Get Started with Quarto"
format: html
editor: visual
execute: 
  echo: true
bibliography: references.bib
---
```

Here is what I got in "Background Jobs" tab.

```
------
=> quarto preview index.qmd --to html --no-watch-inputs --no-browse



processing file: index.qmd
                                                                                                                  
output file: index.knit.md

pandoc 
  to: html
  output-file: index.html
  standalone: true
  title-prefix: Wecome to Quarto
  section-divs: true
  html-math-method: mathjax
  wrap: none
  default-image-extension: png
  
metadata
  document-css: false
  link-citations: true
  date-format: long
  lang: en
  title: 'Hello, Penguins'
  subtitle: Get Started with Quarto
  editor: visual
  bibliography:
    - references.bib

WARNING: The file C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive - xxx xxxx xxxxxx\Documents\Work\xxxxxx\4. Teaching\Center Internship Program\IBM4192\Course Materials\2-1. Data Science\7.0. Create a Report with Quarto\muller\Introducing quarto.qmd contains a theme property which is being ignored. Website projects do not support per document themes since all pages within a website share the website's theme.
ERROR: Jupyter kernel 'julia-1.7' not found. Known kernels: python3. Run 'quarto check jupyter' with your python environment activated to check python version used.

Stack trace:
    at jupyterKernelspecFromMarkdown (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:32003:35)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:183:11)
    at async quartoMdToJupyter (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:31835:36)
    at async createNotebookforTarget (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:38601:16)
    at async Object.target (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:38286:18)
    at async fileExecutionEngineAndTarget (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:41258:20)
    at async renderContexts (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:72183:32)
    at async Object.renderFormats (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:72234:22)
    at async readBaseInputIndex (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:73380:21)
    at async inputTargetIndex (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:73368:19)
```

To solve the problem, I uninstalled, RStudio and R and reinstalled them a few times in no vail. I also installed stand alone Quarto too. Nothing worked. I am not familiar with Python or Julia. I use R only with no other computer programming background. Any assitance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whenever I see issues when trying to compile/render things on a onedrive (or similar), the resolution is often to not work there, move to a not-synced directory, do your work there, then copy it back to onedrive if needed.

Comment: But the mention of `'julia-1.7' not found` suggests that your quarto doc has julia blocks for execution? That's a different thing altogether, not sure how to help other than "check your `PATH`" and how julia was installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have Julia in my system, but I forgot to say that I installed Python via Anaconda to see if that helps. It didn't help.

Comment: Something about your jupyter setup thinks it needs to use julia for that quarto document. If you share (enough of) the document we might be able to help.